# To which object is a flow interview related?

Tags: process-builder, flow

I have created a number of flows with Process Builder, some of them with scheduled actions.

In Setup > Build > Create > Workflows & Approvals > Flows I don't see as many interviews as I expected. The only useful information for me is the Flow Name and Last Modified by attributes. Any way to find out to which objects these interviews are related?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of this writing, the only way to get details on paused flow interviews that were triggered by Process Builder is to log a case and request that SFDC Support use an internal tool to get record IDs.

Answer (score 0):

You only get Paused or Waiting Interviews displayed on the Flows page for the [scheduled actions](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=process_monitor_instance.htm&language=en_US), so any flows that are in progress and have not been paused by the user will not normally appear there.

You are able to see the name of the Paused or Waiting Interviews including the Flow name meaning that you can trace which objects are affected from the Flow definition by opening the flow and seeing which objects it creates or updates.

Unlike normal Workflow rules there can be a large number of objects updated or having records created by each Visual Flow so it is not displayed which objects are affected by the paused interview.

Comment: I have added a picture of Flow Interview detail. I cannot find any link to the related object. Maybe I am overlooking or missing something, hope you can help me.

Comment: Sander the only way to see the objects with a Flow is to actually open the Flow itself and look as unlike a Workflow Rule a Visual Flow can create or update records on any number of Salesforce objects. I'll edit this into the answer.